# How do i direct all my traffic through a US server - can a VPN do this?

Tags: vpn

I have a few servers based in the US.

If i wish to access websites with a US Ip address, is it as simple as setting one of the servers up to accept VPN connections? Then i would direct all traffic over that VPN connection (from a computer outside of the US) to the US based server, which then goes to whatever website .. thus giving my ip address, to that being my US based server?

#### Updated

Reworded the post to (more) clearly state the question.

#### Bonus Question

Could anyone provide links to help set up a Windows 2008 server to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, quite easy to do. Use any VPN software to connect to your US-based machines, and connect to the rest of the internet from there.

Answer (score 2):

While a VPN would allow this what you really want is a Proxy Server.  There's are a bunch of free ones available but they are normally pretty slow.  There are also many that charge you for the service and they tend to be much faster.

A plugin like [foxyproxy](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/) is very handy for this stuff as you can pick what domains go through the proxy and which ones use your local internet connection natively.  They also have a [proxy list](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/proxylists.html) and instructions on [how to setup your own private proxy](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/howto.html) on their website.

Comment: i've got my own Squid proxy server set up on one of my US servers, but i also need NON HTTP traffic (eg. UDP, etc) to go via the VPN, unfortunately. Agreed though -> having a proxy server is an easy way to do this, if i didn't need non web traffic also.

Comment: Yeah if you need traffic other than HTTP then the VPN is the way to go.